# Sort by distance in Lucene.net Spatial 3.0.3

Tags: c#, sorting, lucene.net, spatial

I have a application in which I need to search by geo coordinates. My index is building fine, I am using the PointVectorStragegy.

I am able to search within a circle

```
Point p = spatialContext.MakePoint(latitude, longitude);
var circle = spatialContext.MakeCircle(latitude, longitude, DistanceUtils.Dist2Degrees(distance, DistanceUtils.EARTH_EQUATORIAL_RADIUS_MI));
var args = new SpatialArgs(SpatialOperation.IsWithin, circle);
var filter = strategy.MakeFilter(args);
var records = searcher.Search(booleanQuery, filter, data.Page * pageSize, sort);
```

The results I get back are fine, but they are ordered in descending order, the closest are last. As of now, I am using   `Sort.RELEVANCE`.

Does anyone know how I could sort the results on searching ? Implement a custom sorting ? Is there already one ? 
If anyone does have some code, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked around a bit and tried different things.
What I have done and it works is the following:

```
sort = new Sort(new SortField("Distance", SortField.SCORE, false));
```

True to get the closest first, false otherwise.